# Replace whitespace after every two words by a symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace whitespaces after two words in a text string.
Let's say we are replacing the with the `@` symbol.

Examples:

Input: `this is a sample text`

Output: `this is@a sample@ text`

Input: `can we check this quickly now`

Output: `can we@check this@quickly now`

```
text = "this is a sample text"
flag = 0     
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    if (text[i] == ' '):
        flag += 1
        if(flag%2 == 0):
            text = text.replace(text[i], '@')
print(text)
```

Output: `this@is@a@sample@text`

The problem seems to be that when the `replace` function is invoked it is replacing the whitespace in the whole sentence and not at the index itself.

Is there some other way to tackle this?

Comment: You can pass a 3rd parameter to `. replace()`  that will limit the number of substitutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.replace` replaces all the occurrence if count not provided, and is position independent, it starts from first.

You can use slice assignment instead:

```py
text = "this is a sample text"
flag = 0     
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    if (text[i] == ' '):
        flag += 1
        if(flag%2 == 0):
            text = text[:i] + '@' + text[i+1:]
print(text)
```

```
this is@a sample@text
```

NOTE: strings are immutable in python. So every time you are doing `text = text[:i] + '@' + text[i+1:]` you are creating brand new list. An efficient way is to convert the text to `text_list = list(text)` then perform the operation by changing the list element at index i.

Answer (score 2):

Split and join

```
words = "this is a sample text".split()
out = ''.join(f'{w} ' if i%2 == 0 else f'{w}@' for i, w in enumerate(words))
out = out.strip('@') if len(words) % 2 == 0 else out.strip(' ')
```

Output

```
this is@a sample@text
```

Comment: For odd text length (no. of words) o/p is similar but for even length sentence it puts an @ at the end as well.

Comment: You could just `s.strip('@')` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Split the text up into words, create a word-iterator and yield strings of n-words, join all groups with `"@"`:

```
def seperate_n(text, n, char="@"):

    def get_chunks():
        from itertools import islice
        words = iter(text.split())

        while chunk := " ".join(islice(words, n)):
            yield chunk

    return char.join(get_chunks())

print(seperate_n("this is a sample text", 2))
```

Output:

```
this is@a sample@text
>>>
```

Comment: This is showing an error in python 3.7. Is this due to the assignment expression in while statement?

Comment: Yes, sorry - the "walrus operator" is only available in 3.8+

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents, using regex could be more readable:

```py
import re

text = "this is a sample text"
text = re.sub(r"( [^ ]*) ", r"\1@", text)
print(text)
```